# UNION statement in query

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote a query but I got following error, Any ideas ?!

Error :

```
Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in E:\AppServ\www\admin\index.php on line 545
```

Code :

```
                    require_once '../_db/databaseConnect.php';
                    $db = new databaseConnect();
                    $db->connect();
                    $queryResult = mysql_query("(SELECT * FROM tabelcomments WHERE publishStatus = 2) UNION (SELECT appTitleFa FROM tableapps WHERE appID = '$appID');");
                    for ($dataCnt = 0; $dataCnt < mysql_num_rows($queryResult); $dataCnt++) 
                      {
                         //codes...
                      }
                    $db->close();
```

Comment: For debugging purposes, try adding an `or die(mysql_error())` before the semicolon at the end of your `mysql_query` row. This should probably be taken out before moving your code to production. It looks like you're getting some kind of error with your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both parts of a `UNION` should return the **same amount** and **same type of columns**.

Most likely, your `tabelComments` table contains more columns than the single column returned from the `tableApps` table in the second part of your union.

You can fix this by explicitly selecting the appropriate column(s) from `tableComments` or add dummy columns to the `UNION`part.

Example

```
SELECT NULL as dummycol1, comment FROM tablecomment
UNION SELECT appTitleFa, NULL as dummycol2 FROM tableapps
```

Comment: So Is there any another for this type of querys?

Comment: @iSun: We would need much more information to answer that question. We have no idea what kind of data the tables contain or what kind of result you're trying to achieve. If you need further help, it would probably be better to post another question.

Comment: Usually having a UNION between dissimilar tables is wrong in the first place. But if you really need to do it, add enough `NULL`s to the smaller query to make them match up. You also may need to do type conversions of some of the columns to make the types match.